# Citrix printing permissions

Tags: permissions, printing, citrix

Im trying to get some users printing from a remote citrix server at another company.  It seems as though they require local administrator privileges to do so, however Ive been instructed not to give them that.

They can print normally from their desktop without issue.

Is there some special permission to allow citrix to print through to local/network printers short of granting local admin to these users?

Comment: Does it require administrator permission even if the driver is already installed?

Comment: So far, yes.  Since they can print locally with no issue as non-admins without being in citrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the short answer is that the temp directory for those users was set to something it shouldnt have been.

Answer (score 0):

I have limited experience with Citrix, but we have some users using it over a VPN connection into another network and they certainly don't have admin rights on Windows (MacOS is another story). What I had to do after the last upgrade though is making sure they use the native client, not the java one and after this, printing worked well.

This is used here for some years now and some (maybe historic) limit is/was, that Citrix only uses the default printer of the local user and this printers name had a very small name length limit (Where "Hewlett Packard Laserjet 4300 PCL6" got renamed to LJ4300PCL).

Comment: the names are short already, and they can print if they are local admin, just not as a limited user.